# Draw curved lines to connect points in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I am trying to plot curved lines to join points, here is the code I am using:-

```py
def hanging_line(point1, point2):
    a = (point2[1] - point1[1])/(np.cosh(point2[0]) - np.cosh(point1[0]))
    b = point1[1] - a*np.cosh(point1[0])
    x = np.linspace(point1[0], point2[0], 100)
    y = a*np.cosh(x) + b

    return (x,y)

n_teams = 4
n_weeks = 4

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))

t = np.array([
    [1, 2, 4, 3],
    [4, 3, 3, 2],
    [3, 4, 1, 4],
    [2, 1, 2, 1]
])

fig.patch.set_facecolor('#1b1b1b')

for nw in range(n_weeks):
    ax.scatter([nw] * n_weeks, t[:, nw], marker='o', color='#4F535C', s=100, zorder=2)
    
ax.axis('off')
    
for team in t:
    x1, x2 = 0, 1
    
    for rank in range(0, len(team) - 1):
        y1 = n_weeks - team[rank] + 1
        y2 = n_weeks - team[rank + 1] + 1
        x, y = hanging_line([x1, y1], [x2, y2])
        ax.plot(x, y, color='#4F535C', zorder=1)
        x1 += 1
        x2 += 1
```

The code is producing the following output:-
[image]

But I want the curved lines to look somewhat like this:
[image]

What changes should I have to do in my code to get the required result?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is an approach using [bezier curves](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/shapes_and_collections/quad_bezier.html).

The sequence `[...., i-indent, i, i + 0.8, ...]` will put control points at each integer position `i` and some space before and after. The plot below used `indent=0.8`; `indent=0` would create straight lines; with `indent>1` the curves would be intersecting more. Other variations will make the curves more or less "cornered".

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np

n_teams = 4
n_weeks = 4
t = np.array([[1, 2, 4, 3],
              [4, 3, 3, 2],
              [3, 4, 1, 4],
              [2, 1, 2, 1]])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 4), facecolor='#1b1b1b')
ax.set_facecolor('#1b1b1b')

indent = 0.8
for tj in t:
    ax.scatter(np.arange(len(tj)), tj, marker='o', color='#4F535C', s=100, zorder=3)
    # create bezier curves
    verts = [(i + d, tij) for i, tij in enumerate(tj) for d in (-indent, 0, indent)][1:-1]
    codes = [Path.MOVETO] + [Path.CURVE4] * (len(verts) - 1)
    path = Path(verts, codes)
    patch = patches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='none', lw=2, edgecolor='#4F535C')
    ax.add_patch(patch)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.autoscale() # sets the xlim and ylim for the added patches
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

A colored version could look like:

```py
colors = ['crimson', 'skyblue', 'lime', 'gold']
for tj, color in zip(t, colors):
    ax.scatter(np.arange(len(tj)), tj, marker='o', color=color, s=100, zorder=3)
    verts = [(i + d, tij) for i, tij in enumerate(tj) for d in (-indent, 0, indent)][1:-1]
    codes = [Path.MOVETO] + [Path.CURVE4] * (len(verts) - 1)
    path = Path(verts, codes)
    patch = patches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='none', lw=2, edgecolor=color)
    ax.add_patch(patch)
```

[image: colored version]

The following plot compares different values for `indent`:

[image: comparing indents]

Answer (score 7):

You can do this by customizing the `connectionstyle` argument of [`FancyArrowPatch`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch.html#matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch). The documentation doesn't explain `fraction` and `angle` of `bar` well, I draw them out by enumeration.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x1, y1 = 0.3, 0.2
x2, y2 = 0.8, 0.6

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

axs[0, 0].plot([x1, x2], [y2, y1], ".")
axs[0, 0].annotate("",
            xy=(x1, y2), xycoords='data',
            xytext=(x2, y1), textcoords='data',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", color="0.5",
                            connectionstyle="bar,angle=180,fraction=-0.3",
                            ),
            )


axs[0, 1].plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], ".")
axs[0, 1].annotate("",
            xy=(x1, y1), xycoords='data',
            xytext=(x2, y2), textcoords='data',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", color="0.5",
                            connectionstyle="bar,angle=180,fraction=-0.3",
                            ),
            )

axs[1, 0].plot([x1, x2], [y2, y1], ".")
axs[1, 0].annotate("",
            xy=(x1, y2), xycoords='data',
            xytext=(x2, y1), textcoords='data',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", color="0.5",
                            connectionstyle="bar,angle=90,fraction=-0.3",
                            ),
            )

axs[1, 1].plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], ".")
axs[1, 1].annotate("",
            xy=(x1, y1), xycoords='data',
            xytext=(x2, y2), textcoords='data',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", color="0.5",
                            connectionstyle="bar,angle=270,fraction=-0.3",
                            ),
            )

for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.set(xlim=(0, 1), ylim=(0, 1), aspect=1)

fig.tight_layout(pad=0.2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

[Annotations — Annotating with Arrow](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/annotations.html#annotating-with-arrow) and [Connectionstyle Demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/userdemo/connectionstyle_demo.html) for reference.

---

Back to your problem. I use two `if` to judge the position of (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) to check which `connectionstyle` they should use.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n_teams = 4
n_weeks = 4

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))

t = np.array([
    [1, 2, 4, 3],
    [4, 3, 3, 2],
    [3, 4, 1, 4],
    [2, 1, 2, 1]
])

fig.patch.set_facecolor('#1b1b1b')

for nw in range(n_weeks):
    ax.scatter([nw] * n_weeks, t[:, nw], marker='o', color='#4F535C', s=100, zorder=2)
    
ax.axis('off')
    
for team in t:
    x1, x2 = 0, 1
    
    for rank in range(0, len(team) - 1):
        y1 = n_weeks - team[rank] + 1
        y2 = n_weeks - team[rank + 1] + 1

        if (x1 < x2 and y1 > y2):
            ax.annotate("",
                    xy=(x1, y1), xycoords='data',
                    xytext=(x2, y2), textcoords='data',
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", color="0.5",
                                    connectionstyle="bar,angle=180,fraction=-0.2",
                                    ),
                    )

        if (x1 < x2 and y1 < y2):
            ax.annotate("",
                        xy=(x1, y1), xycoords='data',
                        xytext=(x2, y2), textcoords='data',
                        arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", color="0.5",
                                        connectionstyle="bar,angle=270,fraction=-0.4",
                                        ),
                        )

        x1 += 1
        x2 += 1

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Here is an example how to enumerate:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x1, y1 = 0.3, 0.3
x2, y2 = 0.6, 0.6

fig, axs = plt.subplots(5, 5)

angle = 0

for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], ".")
    ax.annotate("",
                xy=(x1, y1), xycoords='data',
                xytext=(x2, y2), textcoords='data',
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", color="0.5",
                                connectionstyle=f"bar,angle={angle},fraction=-0.3",
                                ),
                )
    ax.set_title(angle)
    angle += 15
    ax.set(xlim=(0, 1), ylim=(0, 1), aspect=1)

fig.tight_layout(pad=0.2)

plt.show()
```

[image]