# matplotlib - is it possible to create a normal sankey chart?

Tags: matplotlib

Is the possible to matplotlib to create a sankey chart that style is like what plotly created?

Comment: Can you show an example how to use matplotlib to create a sankey like plotly-style sankey? plotly doesn't support by powerBI service, so I want to try matplotlib which is supported by powerBI service.

Comment: Well, it's quite some work, depending on your data and how you want the result to look like.  `plotly` uses some `d3.js` functionality that is hard to mimic with matplotlib.  For the curves you might look into Bézier curves, as in e.g. [Draw curved lines to connect points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63560005/draw-curved-lines-to-connect-points-in-matplotlib/63560635).

Comment: thank you. a bit complicated.

Comment: Here is a [blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-beautiful-sankey-diagrams-with-floweaver-dc1f02fe76bc) about a library called FloWeaver.  There is also a library called [pySankey](https://github.com/anazalea/pySankey) that might be useful.

Comment: Thank you, but they're not supported by PowerBI Service yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a lack of good alternatives, I bit the bullet and tried my hand at creating my own sankey plot that looks more like plotly and sankeymatic. This uses purely Matplotlib and produces flows like below. I don't see the plotly image in your post though, so I don't know what you want it to look like exactly.

[image: sankeyflow example]

Full code at bottom. You can install this with `python -m pip install sankeyflow`. The basic workflow is simply

```py
from sankeyflow import Sankey
plt.figure()
s = Sankey(flows=flows, nodes=nodes)
s.draw()
plt.show()
```

Note that [pySankey](https://github.com/anazalea/pySankey) does use Matplotlib too, but it only allows for 1 level of bijective flow. [SankeyFlow](https://github.com/riley-x/SankeyFlow) is much more flexible, with multiple levels and doesn't have to be bijective, but requires you to define the nodes.

```py
from sankeyflow import Sankey
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10), dpi=144)
nodes = [
    [('Product', 20779), ('Sevice\nand other', 30949)],
    [('Total revenue', 51728)],
    [('Gross margin', 34768), ('Cost of revenue', 16960)],
    [('Operating income', 22247), ('Other income, net', 268), ('Research and\ndevelopment', 5758), ('Sales and marketing', 5379), ('General and\nadministrative', 1384)],
    [('Income before\nincome taxes', 22515)],
    [('Net income', 18765), ('Provision for\nincome taxes', 3750)]
]
flows = [
    ('Product', 'Total revenue', 20779, {'flow_color_mode': 'source'}),
    ('Sevice\nand other', 'Total revenue', 30949, {'flow_color_mode': 'source'}),
    ('Total revenue', 'Gross margin', 34768),
    ('Total revenue', 'Cost of revenue', 16960),
    ('Gross margin', 'Operating income', 22247),
    ('Gross margin', 'Research and\ndevelopment', 5758), 
    ('Gross margin', 'Sales and marketing', 5379), 
    ('Gross margin', 'General and\nadministrative', 1384),
    ('Operating income', 'Income before\nincome taxes', 22247),
    ('Other income, net', 'Income before\nincome taxes', 268, {'flow_color_mode': 'source'}),
    ('Income before\nincome taxes', 'Net income', 18765), 
    ('Income before\nincome taxes', 'Provision for\nincome taxes', 3750),
]

s = Sankey(
    flows=flows,
    nodes=nodes,
)
s.draw()
plt.show()
```

Comment: hi rileyx - thank you the investigation, and the answer is very helpful to start my own sankey with matplotlib.  You are so nice.

Answer (score 0):

The Sankey chart using the [D3Blocks](https://d3blocks.github.io/d3blocks/pages/html/Sankey.html) library will create a d3.js chart but you can create it using Python!

Install first:

```
pip install d3blocks


# Load d3blocks
from d3blocks import D3Blocks

# Initialize
d3 = D3Blocks()

# Load example data
df = d3.import_example('energy')

# Plot
d3.sankey(df, filepath='sankey.html')
```